# The easiest way to access Azure File Storage?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage-files

I need to migrate an application to Azure and I have a Azure Web Application with 50gb storage space and an Azure File Storage with 250gb, that I'll use to store videos, images and other things.

My application stores the files in a folder in the same directory of my application, so It was easy to do, I didn't have to access another server, like Azure File Storage seems to be.

I have access by FTP to my app folder, like It was at the other server, but this folder only have the 50GB of storage. Does exist an way of mapping the 250gb's Azure File Storage folder to my app folder, or I'll have to change my code to use the Azure API?

Answer (score 2):

Your application can work against Azure File shares without code changes. You will need to persist credentials using cmdkey, and then instead of local path, use the file share path or mounted drive within your application. For more information you can refer to:

- [How to use Azure Files on Windows](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/)
- [How to use Azure Files on Linux](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-how-to-use-files-linux/)

Comment: "Applications running in Azure virtual machines or cloud services or from on-premises clients can mount a file share in the cloud, just as a desktop application mounts a typical SMB share."

And what if I have an application published like simple Web Application, that I only have access to the app folder by FTP? I don't know if the an app type "Web Application" is bounded by the three types in the tutorial's mention.

Is there any way to mount the Azure File Storage drive inside this folder or something like this? Or I'll have to change my code to use the Azure Library or REST Api?

Answer (score 0):

I run a batch file on login which runs the following command, you can use whichever drive letter you choose:

```
net use <drive-letter>: /delete /y
net use <drive-letter>: \\<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net\<share-name> /u:<storage-account-name> <storage-account-key>
```

An example with dummy information would look like this:

```
net use t: /delete /y
net use t: \\testaccount.file.core.windows.net\testshare /u:accountname verylongstorageaccountkey
```

Comment: I guess this command only works in a Azure VM. My application is hosted by a simple Azure Web Application that I only have access by FTP to publish the files. I'd like to map the drive inside the application folder like a common folder, but It isn't possible. :(

Comment: This command doesn't only work on an Azure VM. I have built this into the Logon Scripts on my local network and so the network drives reconnect each time someone signs in :)